# trying to make option tag using values from a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two arrays that store everyone's first and last names. I need to combine them and add them all to an option tag.  I am having trouble with this line in particular: `echo "<option value = '". $name ."'>". $name . "</option>";`

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "u";
$password = "p";
$database = "d";
$con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed " . $con->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "select first from employee";
$sql1 = "select last from employee";
$run = mysqli($con,$sql);
$run1 = mysqli($con,$sql1);
$arr = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
$arr1 = mysqli_fetch_array($run1);
$it = getIterator($arr1);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $name = $value . ' ' . $it;
    echo "<option value = '". $name ."'>". $name . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: why are you doing two queries on the same table, why not just 'select first, last from employee' or even 'select CONCAT(first, ' ' , last) as name from employee?

Comment: Please describe your problem.

Comment: @D4V1D i want the to have the option tag display the the value of $name.  So in my html page i have a drop down menu and i want it to have the names of every in the database.

Comment: So where are your `<select></select>` tags?

Comment: @D4V1D the code is between select tags in my actual code.

Comment: What does `getIterator()` do?

Answer (score -1):

PHP variables inside double quotes are 'evaluated', so you could simplify your line with:

```
echo "<option value ='$name'>$name</option>";
```

If you an guarantee that both arrays will match the records, then you could use the $key to pick the values from each array..

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $name = $arr[$key]. ' ' . $arr2[$key];
    echo "<option value = '". $name ."'>". $name . "</option>";
}
```

My suggestion would be to just do 1 query and combine both fields into 1 column

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(first,' ',last) AS name FROM employee";
$query = mysqli($con,$sql);    
while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $name = $user['name'];
    echo "<option value='$name'>$name</option>";
}
```

Comment: Although that is cleaner I am not sure it solves the issue. But I don't understand the issue really.

Comment: i changed it to 

    'echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>";'

and it shows "$name" in the dropdown menu

Comment: Try my last suggestion now - modified above

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)` will fetch one row from the results.

Answer (score -1):

This is the usual way this type of thing is done.

```
$sql = "select first, last from employee"; //select both first and last with one query
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); //execute the query

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { //loop over the result set
    // there are various ways to combine the names, this is one example
    $name = $row['first'] . ' ' . $row['last'];
    echo "<option value=\"$name\">$name</option>";
}
```

The fetch is done inside the while loop definition this way because `mysqli_fetch_array()` only fetches one row from the results. Doing it this way will continue to fetch until it has gone through every row.

Answer (score -1):

Why not  create a reusable function so every time you want to do this you can just call that.

Here is a function I use to create dynamic dropdown lists. You will need to modify to your needs, but this is way better than writing it every time you need it.

```
/**
 * Selects a set of records and returns a string of HTML <option></option> tags of the selected values. This is to be used inside of <select></select> tags.
 *
 * @param string $_IncomingSql The sql query that you want to execute.
 * @param string $_SelectedValue OPTIONAL PARAMETER - The selected item on load. Based on Value.
 * @param string $_FirstValueName OPTIONAL PARAMETER - Add custom item. Usually "Select". This will set the name="" attribute that will be apended to the custom <option> element.
 * @param string $_FirstValue OPTIONAL PARAMETER - Add custom item. Usually "0". This will set the value="" attribute that will be appended to the custom <option> element.
 */
function gfOption($con, $_IncomingSql, $_SelectedValue=0, $_FirstValueName ='', $_FirstValue=0)
{
    $Result = mysqli_query($con, $_IncomingSql);
    if ($Result)
    {
        $Str = '';
        $I=0;
        if ($_FirstValue!='' or $_FirstValueName !='')
        {
            $Str.= '<option value="'.$_FirstValue.'" name="'.$_FirstValueName.'">' . $_FirstValueName . '</option>';
        }
        $C=0;;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result, MYSQL_BOTH))
        {
            $I++;
            $C= count($row);

            if ($C===1)
            {
                $Str.= '<option value="'.$row[0].'" name="'.$row[0].'" ';
            }
            elseif($C===2)
            {

                $Str.= '<option value="'.$row[0].'" name="'.$row[1].'" ';

            }

            if ($_SelectedValue ==$row[0])
            {
                $Str.= 'Selected="selected"';
            }
            if ($C===1)
            {
                $Str.= '>'.$row[0].'</option>';
            }
            elseif($C===2)
            {
                $Str.= '>'.$row[1].'</option>';
            }
        }
        return $Str;
    }
    return '0';
}
```

And then you would just call it like:

```
<?PHP $Sql = "Select ID, Name from Table order by id;"; ?>

<select id="Select1"> 
<?php echo gfOption($Sql, 0, "Select", "0") ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? At least tell me. I converted from my sqlsrv version so please let me know if you see mysqli issues.

Comment: Mysqli looks fine to me, except for one minor thing. Shouldn't `mysqli(..` be `mysqli_query(...`?